# Vaishnavite sects that have a Moola form other than Vishnu/Narayana

Tags: vaishnavism, sects

We have Gaudiyas and Ramanandis for whom the moola form is Krishna and Rama respectively.

Are there any sects that claim Varaha or Narasimha or Parashurama et al are the moola form?